# problema con imagen de fondo o musica inno setup-ide

Tags: inno-setup

que tal?, tengo un problema con mi codigo.
el problema es que puedo elegir si tener musica utilizando este codigo:

```
function BASS_Init(device: Integer; freq, flags: DWORD; win: hwnd; CLSID: Integer): Boolean;
external 'BASS_Init@files:BASS.dll stdcall';

function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: PAnsiChar; offset1: DWORD; offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): DWORD;
external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:BASS.dll stdcall';

function BASS_Start(): Boolean;
external 'BASS_Start@files:BASS.dll stdcall';

function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: BOOL): Boolean;
external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:BASS.dll stdcall';

function BASS_Stop(): Boolean;
external 'BASS_Stop@files:BASS.dll stdcall';

function BASS_Free(): Boolean;
external 'BASS_Free@files:BASS.dll stdcall';

const
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  mp3Handle: HWND;
  mp3Name: string;
begin
  RedesignWizardForm;
  ExtractTemporaryFile('sound.mp3');
  mp3Name := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\sound.mp3');
  BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0);
  mp3Handle := BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, PAnsiChar(mp3Name), 0, 0, 0, 0, BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
  BASS_Start();
  BASS_ChannelPlay(mp3Handle, False);
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  BASS_Stop();
  BASS_Free();
end;

procedure RedesignWizardForms;
begin
  with WizardForm.ProgressGauge do
  begin
    Height := ScaleY(13);
  end;
```

creo recordar que lo saque de esta web, y funciona perfectamente.
el problema es que tambien tengo esto que es la imagen de fondo

```
#define ISSI_BackgroundImage "C:\ISSI\03_side.bmp"
```

me di cuenta que usando el fondo o la música funcionan perfectamente, pero si activo los dos, solo funciona el fondo por estar arriba en el código.

también estuve probando de utilizar este código, que encontré por esta web:

```
files
Source: "C:\Users\nahue\Desktop\probando\back.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

code
procedure InitializeWizarda();
var
  BackgroundImage: TBitmapImage;
begin
  BackgroundImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
  BackgroundImage.Parent := MainForm;
  BackgroundImage.SetBounds(0, 0, MainForm.ClientWidth, MainForm.ClientHeight);
  BackgroundImage.Stretch := True;
  ExtractTemporaryFile('C:\Users\nahue\Desktop\probando\back.bmp');
  BackgroundImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\C:\Users\nahue\Desktop\probando\back.bmp'));
end;
```

tambien probe en estas lineas

```
`ExtractTemporaryFile('C:\Users\nahue\Desktop\probando\back.bmp');`
BackgroundImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('back.bmp'));
```

quitar c:/... y dejar unicamente el back.bmp

pero no funciona o sea no carga, coloque lo de WindowVisible=true pero me lo deja en azul(por defecto) en inno ide, probe inno setup pero es lo mismo.

espero que me puedan ayudar porque ya no se que hacer.
saludos y muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se extrae llamándola por el nombre a la carpeta temporal:

```
ExtractTemporaryFile('back.bmp');
```

La cargas con ExpandConstant indicando la constante `{tmp}` de la carpeta temporal:

```
BackgroundImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\back.bmp'));
```

Quedari algo asi:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\nahue\Desktop\probando\back.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizarda();
var

  BackgroundImage: TBitmapImage;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('back.bmp');//Se extrae a la carpeta temporal del instalador
  BackgroundImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
  BackgroundImage.Parent := MainForm;
  BackgroundImage.SetBounds(0, 0, MainForm.ClientWidth, MainForm.ClientHeight);
  BackgroundImage.Stretch := True;      
  BackgroundImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\back.bmp'));//se carga desde la carpeta temporal del instalador
end;
```